# Looking for the corollary 3.25 of the book Cardinal functions in topology: ten years later

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

One of recently reading papers cited the corollary 3.25 of  the book Cardinal functions in topology: ten years later. However I have no this book and I tried to look for it by google.
It is difficult to find it.  Could Somebody help me? What did the corollary said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book is freely available as a PDF [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_function#References). The result is:

> 3.25. If $X\in\mathcal{C}_2$, then $\pi sw(X)\le t(X)$.

Here $\mathcal{C}_2$ is the class of compact Hausdorff spaces, and

$$\pi sw(X)=\min\{\operatorname{ord}(\mathcal{B}):\mathcal{B}\text{ is a }\pi\text{-base of }X\}\;,$$ where

$$\operatorname{ord}(\mathcal{B})=\sup\{\operatorname{ord}(p,\mathcal{B}):p\in X\}\;,$$ and

$$\operatorname{ord}(p,\mathcal{B})=|\{B\in\mathcal{B}:p\in B\}|\;.$$

It has the following corollary:

> COROLLARY. If $X\in\mathcal{C}_2$ and $t(X)^+$ is a calibre for $X$, then $\pi(X)\le t(X)$.

Comment: What is $\pi$-base?

Comment: @Paul: A family $\mathscr{P}$ of open subsets of $X$ is a $\pi$-base for $X$ if every non-empty open set in $X$ contains a member of $\mathscr{P}$. For example, the set of open intervals with rational endpoints is a countable $\pi$-base for the Sorgenfrey line, even though the weight of the Sorgenfrey line is $2^\omega$.

Comment: By the definition, it seems no different from the usual base $mathcal{B}$. Every non-empty open set always also contains a member of $mathcal{B}$. Am I right?

Comment: @Paul: I gave the example in the Sorgenfrey line to show that there is a difference: the Sorgenfrey line has a countable $\pi$-base, but it does not have a countable base. If $\mathscr{P}$ is a $\pi$-base, $\mathscr{B}$ is a base, and $U\ne\varnothing$ is open, there must be $\mathscr{B}_0\subseteq\mathscr{B}$ such that $U=\bigcup\mathscr{B}_0$. $U$ need not be the union of any $\mathscr{P}_0\subseteq\mathscr{P}$, however; $U$ just has to contain **one** member of $\mathscr{P}$.

Comment: @Paul: For example, in the Sorgenfrey line the open set $[0,1)$ contains $(0,1)\in\mathscr{P}$, but there is no open interval $(a,b)$ with rational endpoints such that $0\in(a,b)\subseteq[0,1)$, so $\mathscr{P}$ isn’t a base.

Comment: O, I see. Thanks:)

Comment: @Paul: You’re welcome!